# How to use aggregate filter in logstash config file?

Tags: postgresql, logstash

I am trying to use `aggregate` filter in logstash config file to combine results from two sql tables but can't figure out where the problem is.

My current logstash config file looks like this:

```
input {
    jdbc {

        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school"
        jdbc_user => "postgres"
        jdbc_password => "postgres"
        jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/karangupta/Downloads/postgresql-42.2.8.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
        jdbc_paging_enabled => true
        statement => "select 
                          s.id as "sch_id", 
                          s.udise_sch_code as "sch_code",
                          tch.teacher_id as "tch_id", 
                          tch.name as "tch_name",
                          tch.social_category as "social_cat" 
                      from mst_school s 
                      inner join teacher_profile tch on s.id = tch.id limit 100 " 
        }

filter {
    aggregate {
        task_id => "%{sch_id}"
        code => “
        map[sch_id] = event.get(sch_id) 
        map[sch_code] = event.get(sch_code) 
        map[‘teachers’] ||= []
        map[‘teachers’] << {‘tch_id’ => event.get(‘tch_id’),’tch_name’ => event.get(‘tch_name’),’social_cat’ => event.get(‘social_cat’)}
        event.cancel()
        "
    push_previous_map_as_event => true
    timeout => 30

    }
}


output {
     stdout { codec => json_lines }
 }

#output {
#   elasticsearch {
#       index => "detfac"
#       hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
#           }
#       }
```

and here is the error that I get:

```
Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Expected one of #, {, } at line 11, column 36 (byte 409) after input {\n    jdbc {\n       \n        jdbc_connection_string => \"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school\"\n        jdbc_user => \"postgres\"\n        jdbc_password => \"postgres\"\n        jdbc_driver_library => \"/Users/karangupta/Downloads/postgresql-42.2.8.jar\"\n        jdbc_driver_class => \"org.postgresql.Driver\"\n        jdbc_paging_enabled => true\n        statement => \"select \n                          s.id as \"", :backtrace=>["/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.3.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:41:in `compile_imperative'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.3.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:49:in `compile_graph'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.3.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:11:in `block in compile_sources'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2577:in `map'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.3.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/compiler.rb:10:in `compile_sources'", "org/logstash/execution/AbstractPipelineExt.java:151:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:47:in `initialize'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.3.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:24:in `initialize'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.3.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in `execute'", "/usr/local/Cellar/logstash/7.3.2/libexec/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:325:in `block in converge_state'"]}
```

Is there any other way to do this? or any help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your error message: "`Expected one of #, {, } at line 11, column 36 (byte 409) after input...`". If you go at those coordinates in your configuration file, you will notice that you are using quotes which interfere with the ones of the `statement` property. Try removing all quotes within the statement, or escape them (see how on the [Logstash documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/configuration-file-structure.html#_escape_sequences)).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code,

```
input {
jdbc {

    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/school"
    jdbc_user => "postgres"
    jdbc_password => "postgres"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/Users/karangupta/Downloads/postgresql-42.2.8.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "org.postgresql.Driver"
    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    statement => "select 
                      s.id as sch_id, 
                      s.udise_sch_code as sch_code,
                      tch.teacher_id as tch_id, 
                      tch.name as tch_name,
                      tch.social_category as social_cat 
                  from mst_school s 
                  inner join teacher_profile tch on s.id = tch.id limit 100 " 
    }
filter {
aggregate {
    task_id => "%{sch_id}"
    code => "
    map[sch_id] = event.get(sch_id) 
    map[sch_code] = event.get(sch_code) 
    map['teachers'] ||= []
    map['teachers'] << {'tch_id' => event.get('tch_id'),'tch_name' => event.get('tch_name'),'social_cat' => event.get('social_cat')}
    event.cancel()
    "
push_previous_map_as_event => true
timeout => 30

} }
```